# How to create a script to run Terminal commands?

Tags: python, ruby, linux, raspberry-pi, siri

I build a Siri proxy with my Raspberry Pi (I used [The-Three-Little-Pigs-Siri-Proxy](https://github.com/jimmykane/The-Three-Little-Pigs-Siri-Proxy)) and I'd like to start the proxy on startup.

Is it possible to create a python or ruby script that starts the server?

To start the server I have to type: `cd siriproxy` and `rvmsudo siriproxy server`. I already know how to execute commands and scripts on startup, but i don't know how to start the siri proxy with a script.

Comment: Please clarify - You say that you would like to start the proxy with a scipt? 
Does creating "start.sh" with "cd siriproxy ; rvmsudo siriproxy server" inside does the job for you? (use bash start.sh then)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a clear programming question to me

Comment: What is the OS you are using (Debian/Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a script in the `/usr/bin` folder.

Like:

1. Make a script : add a line to include the complete path of startup command
2. /path/to/siriproxy/rvmsudo siriproxy server
3. chmod 777
4. To make it accessible globally, copy it to /usr/bin or add the folder which contains the script to the PATH

Comment: For auto start up : put it in /etc/rc5.d/ folder ...suppose your script name SCRIPT just copy it and add the Suffix S111...so ur script becomes S111SCRIPt.....cp SCRIPT /etc/rc5.d/S111SCRIPT....

Comment: I only need the command i can start the proxy with, I know how to start the script on startup

Comment: Ok. For starting the proxy , just create the script and run it. Like ./SCRIPT

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a .sh file and place it inside /usr/bin.  You identify the command lines you wanted to see being executed in that .sh file and set for it to be fired at the startup.  Dont forget to 777 that file.

Answer (score 0):

Create `/etc/rc5.d/S111start_siriproxy.sh`. Its contents should be:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd /full/path/to/siriproxy
rvmsudo siriproxy server
```

At the command prompt, type

```bsh
$ chmod 755 /etc/rc5.d/S111start_siriproxy.sh
```

And that should be it.